# Restrict use of an attribute in an XSD assertion

Tags: xml, xsd, assertions, xsd-1.1

Given XSD:

```
<xs:element name="color">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="type">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="white"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="black"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="number" use="optional/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How would I write an assertion so that

1. if `<color>` has `@type` white or black, it cannot also have the `@number` attribute, **and**
2. if `<color>` has `@type` red or green, it must also have the `@number` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="color">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="type">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="white"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="black"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="number" use="optional"/>
            <xs:assert test="   (@type = ('white','black') and not(@number))
                             or (@type = ('red','green') and @number)"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Added this answer belatedly since other questions point here)*

Another XSD 1.1 solution here is to use type alternatives:

```
<xs:element name="color" type="colorType">
  <xs:alternative test="@type = ('white', 'black')" type="color-without-number"/>
  <xs:alternative test="@type = ('red', 'green')" type="color-with-number"/>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="colorType">
  <xs:attribute name="type" .../>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="color-without-number">
  <xs:restriction base="colorType">
    ...
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="color-with-number">
  <xs:restriction base="colorType">
    ...
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:complexType>
```

A potential benefit of using type alternatives over assertions is that the implementation is more likely to be streamable (that is, validation doesn't require building the document tree in memory). And if you're using schema-aware XSLT or XQuery, you get more precise type information attached to nodes.