# XSD 1.0 set attribute to false if another has no value

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.0

I am trying to write a schema where I have two attributes `ID` and `required`:

- `ID` can be any string or empty string
- `required` is boolean true/false

I need to set `required` to false if `ID` has no text.

I searched all over this place and found this can be done using XSD 1.1, but I don't have access to this because its not supported in Visual Studio 2017.  Is there an alternative to this in XSD 1.0 ?

This a part of the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       
    <xs:element name="sizeGroup">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="required" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSDs *constrain* or *require* properties of XML documents; they do not *set* properties.

Assuming you mean that you wish to *require*, not *set*, an attribute to have a certain value based on another attribute's value, no, such a constraint cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0.  You'll need XSD 1.1 assertions.

**Note further:** Requiring that an attribute value be derived from content already present in another XML component is often a sign of design weakness.

### See also

- [Restrict use of an attribute in an XSD assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37186870/290085)

Comment: Yes I meant require not set. That is unfortunate I was relying on Visual Studio and XmlNotepad to modify my project XML files. Anyway thanks for the info.